# Streamplot not working outside of the mgrid example

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 128x128 vector field that I want to use to plot streamlines in python. I have two arrays for the coordinates, x1 and x2, and two arrays for the vector components, b1 and b2. When I naively plug these into streamplot, i.e.

```
plt.streamplot(x1, x2, b1, b2, color='k', linewidth=2)
```

I get a nondescriptive error which concludes as

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/streamplot.pyc in __init__(self, x, y)
    252         if len(x.shape) == 2:
    253             x_row = x[0]
--> 254             assert np.allclose(x_row, x)
    255             x = x_row
    256         else:

AssertionError:
```

I can make a streamplot if I construct coordinate variables from mgrid, as in the example (bounds modified here)

```
Y, X = np.mgrid[x1[0][0]:x1[127][0]:128j, x2[0][0]:x2[0][127]:128j]
```

However, this always seems to either flip the x and y axes when making a plot or cause errors similar to above if I try to correct that problem by switching around the inputs in streamplot(). Also, I would like to be able to use streamplot for non-uniform coordinates which I think would preclude the use of mgrid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.